# Call an event on Bootstrap panel expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a flow where we are using Bootstrap styled accordion (NOT jQuery UI accordion). The requirement is to call a service when the user expands the accordion. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="accordion-dashboard">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading  row-white" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#runtimeValue">                 
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="badge blue">A</span></td>
                        <td><strong>Aenean ultricies est lorem,id feugiat velit euismod ut.Nullam inia.Prasent vel nu Sed ante mauris, eu lacus..</strong></td>
                        <td><i class="icon8 icon-paperclip"></i></td>
                        <td><span class="time">5 mins</span></td>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>                        
            </div>
            <div id="runtimeValue" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-1">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-muted">By</td>
                                    <td><img width="24px" src="images/company-logo.png"> Company Admin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-muted">On</td>
                                    <td class="text-muted">Friday- 7 Aug 2014, 9.00PM</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="icon8 icon-paperclip"></i></td>
                                    <td>dummyfile.pdf</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <h5>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.</h5>
                                        <p>Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 pull-right">
                            <span data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="btn-close icon8"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

`HREF` attribute and the correspoding `id` attributes will be decided at runtime and I am aware of the pattern of them. One approach could be binding an event on click of the accordion, but I want to have it as a last resort.

Is there any other way I can call a service when the user clicks and expands the accordion?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L614) (admittedly for the most current version, 3.3.0), there should be a `shown.bs.collapse` event emitted once the transition is complete. You can hook into that.

Answer (score 30):

You can use :-

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       //call a service here 
});
```

Comment: this event is triggered after click and not when the transition is finished. should be used 'shown.bs.collapse' event to fire after animation is finished.

Answer (score 3):

You can check this for: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php. This will help surely.

```
show.bs.collapse
```

This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can fire the function and get the corresponding id of that opened accordion with this code.

```
jQuery(document).on('show.bs.collapse','#your-accordion',function (e){
    var clicked = $(document).find("[href='#" + $(e.target).attr('id') + "']");
    // Your awesome code
});
```