# How do you make the link doesn't scroll you at the top page after clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code on JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ddy3353q/3/

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome-animation/0.0.10/font-awesome-animation.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div style="background-color:red; height: 1000px">
    LINK AT THE BOTTOM
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="work-exp-collapse">

    <div>TEST HIDDEN DIV HELLO!!</div>

  </div>
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; display: block">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-down yarrow"></i>  <a aria-controls="work-exp-collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="aa-gray-line SeeMore2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#work-exp-collapse">view more experience</a>
  </div>

</body>
<!-- JS code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Recpatcha Google -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js">
</script>
<!--JS below-->

</html>
```

I wonder how I could make it to avoid when you click on the link it automatically scroll your screen at the top of the page instead of stay at the same position where the hidden div appear.

Thanks

Comment: I've updated the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddy3353q/4/), just comment out `$('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused the `target` element is not shown yet, thus `target.offset().top` is `0`.

Just wait for the hidden div to be shown by listening `shown.bs.collapse` (fired by Boostrap, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26751025/1099314)) and do your scroll.

```
  if (target.length) {
    target.one('shown.bs.collapse', function() {        
       $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: target.offset().top
       }, 1000);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ddy3353q/5/

Comment: Hello there. Thank you for all the reply. I am a little confused. Im not the best with js.  What should I do then?.

Comment: Replace above block code to your JS code from line `6` to line `11`. Or you might check a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddy3353q/5/

Comment: Hello it works with THAT link but now the rest of ordinary anchor links are not working. When I click them they don't go to #

I have update your https://jsfiddle.net/ddy3353q/6/ 

I have added an ordinary link

Comment: It should check Boostrap collapse elements. Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/ddy3353q/7/

Comment: You are God with the JS.  It works now!. Thank very much!

Comment: Thanks, I'm just a grain in the desert .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to auto-scroll to see the content of the div you just un-collapsed by clicking...

From the docs: "jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements". So initially the element you're trying to scroll to is collapsed, and its position cannot be determined with `.offset()`.

One way to solve this is to wrap the `.animate()` call in a `setTimeout()` with a delay of `1`. This effectively delays the scrolling until the element has begin to display.